# Reactjs CSSTransition Component props in TransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I'm currently looking into animate a set of divs. I came across this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/43v5wj62q9?file=/index.js:1115-1119) and it is exactly what i need. As im still a noobie in react, i dont really understand how the props are being fed throw the `<Fade>` component, inparticular the Fade params `({ children, ...props })`. If someone can shed some light that will be greatly appreciated it..

Here is the snippet of `Fade`

```jsx
const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <CSSTransition
    {...props}
    timeout={1000}
    classNames="fade"
  >
    {children}
  </CSSTransition>
);
```

Here is the usage:

```jsx
<div className='container'>
  <TransitionGroup className='todo-list'>
    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
      <Fade key={item}>
        <div>
          {`${item} `}
          <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    ))}
  </TransitionGroup>
  <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd()}>Add Item</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The props are fed to Fade using [**Destructuring Assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
For example

```js
const {children, ...props} = {children: 0, propsA: 1, propsB: 2}
console.log(children); // 0
console.log(props); // {propsA: 1, propsB: 2}
```

`...` represents [**Rest** & **Spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operators

```js
const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (); // This ... is Rest Operator
<CSSTransition {...props}/> // This ... is Spread Operator
```

Here, [**props.children**](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891) is those wrapped by `Fade`, which is:

```
<div>
 {`${item} `}
 <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>
   &times;
 </button>
</div>
```

`Fade` is like to wrap things using `CSSTransition` and conceal some props.
You can actually rewrite as the follows:

```js
<div className='container'>
  <TransitionGroup className='todo-list'>
    {this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
      <CSSTransition key={item} timeout={1000} classNames="fade">
        <div>
          {`${item} `}
          <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    ))}
  </TransitionGroup>
  <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd()}>Add Item</button>
</div>
```